# Fatal error: Call to a member function schemaCollection() on a non-object in ...vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php on line 421

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi everyone and happy Easter !

I have this problem in migrating a legacy application from CakePHP 2.x to CakePHP 3.x

I am trying to load all the contents of a database table in the initialize function of the model (ConfigurationsTable.php - made into a Singleton) class. I also tried the same code in the constructor but still get the same error. Also tried moving it to a separate function but still no luck.

It works fine in CakePHP 2.x but I get a fatal error in CakePHP 3.

Code is as follows

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ConfigurationsTable extends Table
{

private $_configurations;

public static function getInstance()
{
    static $instance = null;

    if ($instance === null) {
        $instance = new static();
    }

    return $instance;
}

public function is_set($key)
{
    return isset($this->_configurations->{$key});
}

public function fetch($key)
{
    return $this->_configurations->{$key};
}

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->_configurations = new \stdClass();

    $configs = $this->find('all');

    foreach ($configs as $c) {
        if (isset($c->key) && $c->key != '') {
            $this->_configurations->{$c->key} = $c->value;
        }
    }


}


public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('key')
        ->add('key', [
            'unique' => [
                'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                'provider' => 'table',
                'message' => __('This configuration key already exists')
            ]
        ])
        ->notEmpty('value')
        ;

    return $validator;
}
```

The line that's causing the error is: $configs = $this->find('all');

Can anyone provide me a solution for this ?
I need it for work..

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot blindly apply 2.x concepts and expect it to work. Before you start working with code that you don't know about, take at least a look at the API docs

**http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#___construct**

and having a look at the source itself to understand what the code actually does would be even better.

When manually instantiating table classes, you must at least provide a [**connection instance**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html). However, what you are doing there doesn't make much sense, there's not really a need for a custom static instance getter, that's what [**`TableRegistry::get()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class) is there for.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and effort and the useful pointers,
I managed to get it working.

Thanks again!